# Should I use join for simple relationships in MySQL

Tags: mysql, join, relationship

Is JOIN the right way (only way?) to add information from other tables?

E.g. 
If I have these tables:

**Employees**

```
name | pay_table
--------------------
John | 1
Lisa | 2
```

**Pay**

```
Id  | Pay
---------------------
1   | 30000
2   | 50000
```

and I need the name and the pay in one table, would the best approach be to write something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM Employees
LEFT JOIN Pay
ON Pay.id = Employees.pay_table
```

? Or is there a better way?

I ask because this often seems very slow even if I only have a few of those kinds of relationships in large tables.

Comment: That is a perfectly good solution

Comment: But is it the best/fastest one?

Comment: Show your slow queries. http://dba.stackexchange.com/ is a good site for pure database questions. [Query Optimization](https://github.com/jynus/query-optimization), [How MySQL uses indexes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-indexes.html) are good starting points however.

Comment: This is an odd mapping in this case because its always 1-1. A properly indexed table i.e. `CREATE INDEX pay_table ON Employees (pay_table)` and assuming Id on Pay is a primary key (or at least a index of some form) will have quick results.

Comment: @danblack Yes, I just typed in the simplest tables I could think of, should perhaps have added another row. Didn't realize that Employees.pay_table would have to be indexed, thought an index on Pay.id would only be needed.

Comment: I can't really think why pay would be a separate table

Comment: @Strawberry This is a simplified table. But there might be 50 people that have the same salary. Having a separate table allows me to change all of their pay at once. That's a simple use case. There might also be more complicated issues, such as if each pay_table has info on when it was last changed, by who, links to contract information etc.

Comment: Sorry, I don't see how that argument applies to this simple use case. But yes, in general indexing and joining is the way to go

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is the right way.

Indexing correctly will solve most preformance problems with joins.

`SHOW CREATE TABLE {table name}` and `EXPLAIN {query}` is the main information required to help solve MySQL performance problems.